# Display bullets toggle button, pressed and not pressed, on custom Word ribbon tab

Tags: vba, ms-word, togglebutton, ribbonx

I created a custom Word ribbon tab, featuring three bullet toggle buttons.

While these buttons function in terms of styles, they appear pressed when I'm on a different line, unlike the behavior of the bullets button in the Home tab.
How do I achieve the same behavior for my custom tab?

I click on the button to unpress it, even when I'm on a line without bullets.

Note that each bullet style is linked to a Word style.
I have a Sub for each bullet style, three scripts in total.
The following is for style2 (bullet "-")

```vb
Sub BulletListStyle2()
'This macro applies the Style 'bullet stlyle 2' to text
    Set Doc = ThisDocument
    
    With ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = ChrW(8208)        ' hyphen "-"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleBullet
        .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(1)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
        .TabPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0.5)
        .ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 0
        With .Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = "Bullet style 2"
    End With
        ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = "Bullet style 2"
    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
    ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
    False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
    wdWord10ListBehavior
End Sub
```

The following is the callback for the toggle-on action, where you can find all the buttons and their corresponding bullet styles.

```vb
'Callback for Toogle onAction
Sub ToggleonAction(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean)
    Dim ListTemplatesCount As Integer
    
    On Error Resume Next        ' Enable error handling
    
    Dim Doc         As Document
    Set Doc = ActiveDocument
    
    If Not Doc Is Nothing Then
        Select Case control.ID
            
            Case Is = "TB11" 'button for 'bullets style 2'
                If pressed Then
                    Call BulletListStyle1
                Else
                    ' Perform actions when button is not pressed
                    Selection.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers
                End If
                
            Case Is = "TB12".    'button for 'bullets style 3'
                If pressed Then
                    Call BulletListStyle2
                Else
                    ' Perform actions when button is not pressed
                    Selection.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers
                End If
                
            Case Is = "TB4".     'button for 'bullets style'
                If pressed Then
                    ' Perform actions when button is pressed
                    Call BulletListStyle0
                Else
                    ' Perform actions when button is not pressed
                    Selection.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers
                End If
        End Select
        
        'Force the ribbon to redefine the control with correct image and label
        myRibbon.InvalidateControl control.ID
    Else
        MsgBox "Active document Not found.", vbExclamation
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Disable error handling
End Sub
```

This is the callback for the toggle button `getpressed`, which requires improvement to address the behaviour exhibited by the toggle button.

```vb
'Callback for togglebutton getPressed
Sub buttonPressed(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef toggleState)
    'toggleState (i.e., true or false) determines how the 'toggle appears _
    on the ribbon (i.e., flusn or sunken).
    
    Dim ListTemplatesCount As Integer
    ListTemplatesCount = ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates.count
    
    Select Case control.ID
        Case Is = "TB11". 'Toggle button for style 
            toggleState = Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdListBullet
            
        Case Is = "TB12"
            toggleState = Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdListBullet
            
        Case Is = "TB4"
            ' Determine the initial toggle state based on the current selection
            toggleState = Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdListBullet
            
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add an event handler to respond to the SelectionChange event. In your event code you will need to invalidate the ribbon.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt would you be able to help to write the VBA code to add an event handler? I have never use this and I can't find useful help on forums

Comment: Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.windowselectionchange and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/using-events-with-the-application-object-word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While implementing the toggle button functionality, I encountered unexpected behavior despite adding the event handler and using <myRibbon.invalidate>. The resulting button acted like a regular button, not a toggle. To address this, I simplified the approach by changing the XML button type to a standard button and streamlining the VBA code. Unfortunately, this didn't lead to the desired toggle functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the ribbon UI state you need to use the *Invalidate* or *InvalidateControl* methods of the *IRibbonUI* interface. These methods invalidate the cached values for all of the controls (or specific one) of the Ribbon user interface.

For example, if an add-in writer implements the `getPressed` callback procedure for a button, the function is called once, the state loads, and then if the state needs to be updated, the cached state is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in place until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the `Invalidate` method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached. The add-in can then force an immediate update of the UI by calling the `Refresh` method.

In your ribbon XML you could add the following callback to get an instance of the `IRibbonUI` interface:

```
<customUI … OnLoad="MyAddinInitialize" …>
```

Then in the code you could have the following callbacks defined:

```
Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI 
 
Sub MyAddInInitialize(Ribbon As IRibbonUI) 
 Set MyRibbon = Ribbon 
End Sub 
 
Sub myFunction() 
 MyRibbon.Invalidate() ' Invalidates the caches of all of this add-in's controls 
End Sub
```

In your case you could use the [Document.SelectionChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.selectionchange?view=vsto-2017) event which is fired when the selection changes in the document window to call the `Invalidate` method.

Finally, you may find the [How Do I detect Text and Cursor position changes in Word using VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55735/how-do-i-detect-text-and-cursor-position-changes-in-word-using-vsto) page helpful.

Comment: Hi @EugeneAstafiev, for the **invalidate Function**, what should I put between ()
I have tried with (Ribbon) but nothing changed. 
Also, I am not able to add the **events handler** and I don't know how to do it. I have found many examples for VSTO but nothing for VBA.
It seems that I dont have as much experience with VBA to be able to handle this.
Could you please help me to add an event handler to respond to the SelectionChange event?

Comment: note that for the **invalidate Function**, if I leave it with empty (), VBA gives syntax error

Comment: @Ana - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.invalidate